# How to resolve lifetime error for mutable reference in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am not sure why the following code does not compile.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct MyItr<'a> {
    cur: &'a i32,
}

impl<'a> Ord for MyItr<'a> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &MyItr) -> Ordering {
        self.cur.cmp(&other.cur)
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialOrd for MyItr<'a> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &MyItr<'a>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for MyItr<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &MyItr) -> bool {
        self.cur == other.cur
    }
}

impl<'a> Eq for MyItr<'a> {}

fn f0<'a>(t0: &'a mut MyItr<'a>, t1: &'a mut MyItr<'a>, i: &'a i32) {
    let t = std::cmp::max(t0, t1);
    t.cur = i;
}

fn f1() {
    let i0 = 1;
    let i1 = 2;
    let mut z0 = MyItr { cur: &i0 };
    let mut z1 = MyItr { cur: &i1 };

    let i2 = 3;
    f0(&mut z0, &mut z1, &i2);
}
```

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling foo v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/foo)
error: `z1` does not live long enough
  --> lib.rs:40:1
   |
39 |     f0(&mut z0, &mut z1, &i2);
   |                      -- borrow occurs here
40 | }
   | ^ `z1` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

My understanding is the borrowed references to `z0` and `z1` are backed once the `f0` invocation ends. However, The compiler seems to assume the borrowed references are not backed.

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 0.20.0-nightly (41e490480 2017-05-16)
```

Comment: "backed" doesn't make sense as a word in this context.  I don't understand what you think is supposed to be happening.

Comment: My understanding is: after the invocation of f0(), borrowing of z0 and z1 are ended so I don't need to keep z0 and z1 instances.

Comment: A clearer phrasing would be "the borrowed references are dropped" or "the borrows end".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems here.  The first is that you've over-specified lifetimes, creating a situation the compiler just can't deal with.

```
fn f0<'a>(t0: &'a mut MyItr<'a>, t1: &'a mut MyItr<'a>, i: &'a i32)
```

You've told the compiler that all the arguments must be pointers with *the same* lifetime.  The compiler can narrow overlapping lifetimes, but in this case that doesn't help.  You've specified that the pointer to the `MyItr`s has the same lifetime as the thing they point to, *and* the outer pointers are mutable.

The second problem is that (even after fixing that), what you're trying to do is just outright unsafe and will lead to dangling pointers.

Here's a *more* minimal example:

```
struct S<'a> {
    ptr: &'a i32,
}

fn f<'b>(t: &'b mut S<'b>, new_ptr: &'b i32) {}

fn main() {
    let i0 = 1;
    let mut s = S { ptr: &i0 };

    let i1 = 2;
    f(&mut s, &i1);
}
```

What is `'b`?  Well, the compiler can *only* narrow lifetimes, so usually you'd just take the lifetimes of everything you're trying to pass and pick the shortest one.  In this case, that would be the lifetime of `i1`.  So, it has to narrow the lifetime of `&s`.  The lifetime on the pointer to `s` itself isn't a problem (you can narrow how long you take a borrow for), but narrowing the inner lifetime (the one used for the `ptr` field) *is* a problem.

If the compiler narrowed the lifetime of `s.ptr`, you would then be able to store `&i1` in that field.  `s` expects `s.ptr` to outlive itself, but that will no longer be true: `i1` will *be destroyed* before `s` is, meaning `s.ptr` will contain a dangling pointer.  And Rust *will not* allow that to happen.

As a result, Rust *can't* narrow `s`'s inner `'a` lifetime... but if it can't narrow it, then that means `'b` must be the full, un-narrowed `'a`.  But wait, that means that `'b` is longer than the lifetime of `s` itself *and* `i1`.  And that's impossible.

Hence the failure.

The solution requires two things.  First, you need to not over-specify lifetimes.  Secondly, you need to ensure that some valid lifetime exists *at all*; in the case of your original code, that means moving `i2` above `z0` and `z1` so that it outlives them.  Like so:

```
fn f0<'a>(t0: &mut MyItr<'a>, t1: &mut MyItr<'a>, i: &'a i32) {
    let t: &mut MyItr<'a> = std::cmp::max(t0, t1);
    t.cur = i;
}

fn f1() {
    let i0 = 1;
    let i1 = 2;
    let i2 = 3;
    let mut z0 = MyItr { cur: &i0 };
    let mut z1 = MyItr { cur: &i1 };

    f0(&mut z0, &mut z1, &i2);
}
```

A rule of thumb: don't just spam a single lifetime everywhere.  Only use the same lifetime for things that should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: @ruimo If you want to read a slightly more type-theoretic explanation , [here's a page of the Rustonomicon that deals with lifetime subtyping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html). In particular, the reason that the compiler can narrow `'a` but not `'b` in `&'a mut S<'b>` is because `&'a mut T` is variant in `'a` and invariant in `T`. It helped me learn to reason about lifetimes better.

Comment: In general, though, the rule "don't just spam a single lifetime everywhere" will get you pretty far.